# Uninstall Helicon Zoo module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helicontech

I have installed Ruby on Rails through Helicon Zoo. Now I would like to uninstall Ruby on Rails module, but am unable to find an "Uninstall" item. Do I have to uninstall Helicon Zoo to uninstall Ruby on Rails?

Answer (score -1):

Go to Add/Remove Programs and uninstall Helicon Zoo Module, Ruby 1.8 and Ruby 1.9.

Comment: There was no "Uninstall" item for Ruby in "Add/Remove Programs". I had to remove the Helicon Zoo module completely, then delete Ruby folder and restore the PATH environment variable.